# PHP SSH conection using phpseclib Net_SSH2

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I'm trying to get remote ssh working on my website (hosted with godaddy).

I have downloaded and placed the phpseclib onto the server and it is seeing it, I am using to following code as recommended by the documentation

```
<?php

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');
define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);

echo "<span>in progress: <br /></span>";

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('197.87.71.51', 2211);

if (!$ssh->login('postgres', 'postgres')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
} else {
    echo "<span>login success<br /></span>";
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->getLog();
echo $ssh->getLastError();

?>
```

I am getting the login failed message and I dont know where to start with debugging this.

I'm not getting any error messages it doesn't really look like anything is happening

Comment: You need to do $ssh->getLog() before the exit. Do that and edit your question to include the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the errors

```
 print_r($ssh->getSFTPErrors());
```

or just

```
$ssh->getErrors()
```

Chapter 5.1.8. Debugging SSH-2 in the documentation

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->getLog();
```

Comment: I tried to use print_r($ssh->getErrors()); and it output 'Array()'

Comment: Depending on the problem, it may be more effective to just look at the output of $ssh->getLastError() (which returns a string) and $ssh->getErrors() (which returns an array) than to sift through the logs.

Comment: To log output, the NET_SSH2_LOGGING constant will need to be defined.
      
       define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX); after include .

Comment: I updated the code in the question to match your suggestions, it is echoing 'Login Failed' but no reasons as to why

Comment: @Trent - you need to do `$ssh->getLog()` before the `exit`. Do that and edit your original question to include the output.